# Random newlines inserted when pasting a chunk of HTML code

Tags: html

I have been coding in HTML for years, but I am a bit of a Wordpress virgin. After failing to find an answer to my problem I submit it below.

In order to extend a Wordpress page quickly I pasted raw HTML into it. The result wasn't too bad EXCEPT for the enormous number of newlines 
 which appear in the final product and completely mess up the formatting.

Even quite short section headings now appear on two lines.

Any advice on how to avoid this happening when pasting large amounts of HTML would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check if there is a `<pre>` element wrapping the area where your HTML should appear.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. No there is no <pre> in the page I am editing or in the code I am pasting. Someone sent me a link https://opensourcehacker.com/2012/01/09/fixing-wordpress-bad-new-lines-extra-when-copy-pasting-html-by-modifying-wpautop-behavior/ - which is like something I have seen before. But the problem is I am a newbie and don't know how to do what it says. Also the website I am editing belongs to a friend who lives a long way away. Should he do the edit, or can I, and if either, how? The <br> is inserted after the first word of every new para, and randomly after that!